# Displaying images from URL in Listview with picasso

Tags: android, image, listview, picasso

I want you to help me solve my problem of loading my images in my listview using picasso.
Here is my code:

```
     ImageView iv =  new ImageView(getActivity().getBaseContext());

              for (int i = 0; i < categories.length(); i++) {

                     HashMap<String, String> map;

                    map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    map.put("titre", name_cat);

                    map.put("description", description);

                    map.put("count_prog", count_pg.toString());

                    iv = new ImageView(getActivity().getBaseContext());
                     Picasso.with(getActivity().getBaseContext()).
                     load(MY_URL_STRING).into(iv);

                    iv.buildDrawingCache();
                    Bitmap bmap = iv.getDrawingCache();
                    map.put("img_cat", toString().valueOf(bmap));

                    listItem.add(map);
    }
```

The image is loaded but not displayed in the list

thank you so much

Comment: Why are you loading an image into an `ImageView`, then attempting (incorrectly) to get a `Bitmap` out of the `ImageView`, then discarding the `ImageView`? Moreover, it seems to be the same image every time (`MY_URL_STRING`). Just get rid of all of this, and load the image into the `ListView` row's `ImageView`, using Picasso, as part of filling in that row's widgets.

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.YOUR_VIEW_ID);//get the image view you want to display the image on
Picasso.with(ACTIVITY_NAME.this).load(YOUR_URL).into(iv);//load the image onto the image view you specified
```

This will display the image on the image view. there are other tutorials on how to do this with listview but this code just put the image onto the imageview